# Rails 3.1 and the right time saved into DB

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, time, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Already a few hours I am struggling with the storing time into database table. The time is there saved like **-1h**. I don't know how to smartly print the time from database with the right shape (= **+1h**). I tried set timezone and stuffs like that, but unfortunately nothing works me.

So as the solution I choose this way:

```
@my_obj.created_at+3600 # +1 hour
```

Exist any better way to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to display the time in the +1 timezone? or have you just noticed a 1-hour discrepancy from the timezone that you are in? Could you just be seeing a daylight-savings error?

Comment: "Are you trying to display the time in the +1 timezone?" - how can I do this one?

Comment: Convert to "local" time as you display it.

Comment: Yes, this I tried. But the result was, that on my local machine it worked pretty nice, but the problem was when I deployed my app to Heroku - and there is other "localtime" (-9h than in middle Europe)

Comment: Yes - this is because the server will have its own local time. That just means you must declare the timezone in your own server. If you don't do this it will simply default to wherever the server farm is sitting. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've set the server's timezone you can use:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.utc_to_local(@my_obj.created_at)
```

?

For more info: have a look at the apidock on this method here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeZone/utc_to_local

If you need to override the server's local timezone, you could set it as a before_filter in your ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  Time.zone = 'London'
end
```

Again apidock is good for more info: http://apidock.com/rails/Time/zone%3D/class

If you don't want to rely on the server's local timezone, you can always use:

```
@my_obj.created_at.in_time_zone('London')
```